# ¿Por qué la función esPar siempre devuelve el mismo valor?

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente mini programa:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool esPar(int num)
{
    return (num % 2) + true;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", esPar(2));
    printf("%d\n", esPar(3));
    return 0;
}
```

Cuando compilo este código con **gcc** y luego lo ejecuto, me da como resultado:

```c
1
1
```

La pregunta es, ¿por qué la función `esPar` siempre devuelve `1`? Aunque el número sea par o impar retorna lo mismo.

Comment: ¿Y el `+ true` qué pinta allí? ¿Has probado de quitarlo?

Comment: Iba a preguntar justo lo mismo que @MauricioContreras, ¿por qué le sumas `true` al resultado que retornas?

Comment: @MauricioContreras Le sumo `+ true` porque me dio curiosidad del porque sale ese resultado..

Comment: lo que pasa es que (num%2) es de tipo incompatible para el tipo de retorno. entonces devuelve true. Si pusieras + false devolveria false.

Comment: Bien visto @toto. Para devolver un booleano puedes comparar con `if`, con un ternario o con el operador de bit a bit `AND`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El tipo `bool` es ciertamente **un tipo primitivo**, tal y como lo son `int` o `float`. **No** es un `typedef` de `int` ni de ningún otro. Y presenta ciertas peculiaridades:

De [la documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types#Boolean_type):

> ## Boolean type
>
> _Bool (also accessible as the macro bool) - type, capable of holding one of the two values: 1 and 0 (also accessible as the macros true and false). 
> Note that conversion to _Bool does not work the same as conversion to other integer types: (bool)0.5 evaluates to 1, whereas (int)0.5 evaluates to ​0​.

Pues ya lo tenemos. El tipo `bool` **siempre va a contener `0` o `1`**. Por lo tanto, aunque hicieramos:

```
bool esPar( int num ) {
  return 10;
}
```

el resultado de la salida sería el mismo:

> 1

Tal y como acertadamente me indican en los comentarios, detallando un poco mas:

```
0 + 1 == 1
1 + 1 == 2
```

**pero**

```
(bool)2 == 1
```

por tanto siempre retorna 1

Comment: Excelente, añadiría que, siguiendo la explicación, `0 + 1` es `1`, `1 + 1` es `2`, pero `(bool)2` es `1`, por tanto siempre retorna `1`

Answer (score 1):

En esta linea de código estás haciendo una función de tipo *bool* para devolver `true` o `false`

```
return (num % 2) + true;
```

Solo le estás diciendo al compilador que `(num % 2)` es posible, así que es `true`, después le sumas `true`, va a seguir siendo `true`. No le estás dando la opción a que te diga si es par o no.

En mi opinión, si no lo resolviste ya, deberías probar con algo como esto:

```
bool esPar(int num)
{
   var resultado = ((num % 2) == 0);
   return resultado;
}
```

Para profundizar podés revisar un post como [este](https://www.abrirllave.com/c/ejercicio-numero-par-o-impar.php).